# Update specific field in mongodb of a spring-boot app using spring-data feature

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

Can we update only specific field in mongodb of a spring-boot app using spring-data feature?

Currently, spring-data provides a save method to update as well as save in a document. If two sets of concurrent updates happen in a single document for the different field, we can lose information. I know we can solve the problem using Mongotemplate. Can we solve these problems using spring-data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Optimistic Locking feature?

The @Version annotation provides syntax similar to that of JPA in the context of MongoDB and makes sure updates are only applied to documents with a matching version. Therefore, the actual value of the version property is added to the update query in such a way that the update does not have any effect if another operation altered the document in the meantime. In that case, an OptimisticLockingFailureException is thrown.

See Spring Documentation:   https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo-template.optimistic-locking

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB 4.0, ACID transactions have arrived in the Document store, enforcing all-or-nothing execution and maintaining data integrity. So, let’s get straight to it by looking at both the synchronous and the reactive execution models.

you could write code like this:

@Transactional
  void insertDocuments() {

```
operations.insert(documentOne);
operations.insert(documentTwo);
```

}

Complete Spring's documentation:

https://spring.io/blog/2018/06/28/hands-on-mongodb-4-0-transactions-with-spring-data

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. but currently, I am using MongoDB 3.6. Is there any solution for the specific version? Thanks